# Wave packets and the uncertainty principle

Tags: quantum-mechanics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, plane-wave

In my lecture course, I am told that a wave packet $\varphi$ is a superposition of plane waves such that $$\varphi = \int a(k) e^{ik-iw(k)t} dk$$ The function $a(k)$ is then linked to probability and used to explain the Heisenberg uncertainty principle. I don't really understand what the function $a(k)$ means and how this concept of wave packets gives evidence of the uncertainty principle.

If someone could shed some light, that'd be great!

Comment: Hint: Do you know what a Fourier transform is?

Comment: Look closely at a Fourier series, with its individual terms, and compare it to a Fourier integral. What's the difference?

Comment: @NickP  I haven't done any fourier series yet! We do it next year :(

Comment: @Countto10 I haven't done any fourier series yet! We do it next year :(